# How to scrape icon link of image using mechanize gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, ruby-on-rails-5, mechanize

I have a url where I have to **scrape** all images using `mechanize` gem, but some image url's are in `rel=icon`.

I have to get the image from this url:

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/cropped-favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
```

This is my code I tried which **scrapes** only images. How to get both working as one.

```
require 'mechanize'
url = "https://mywebsite.com/"

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(url)

page.images.each do |image|
  puts image #getting here all images here from image tag
end
```

Comment: Do you want just those with `rel='icon'`? I see 3 of them

Comment: @razvans yes, all images included in `link rel="icon"`  tag and `a href` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked over [Mechanize Page Link](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize/Page/Link) but it returns only the `anchors`.

Tried it with `xpath`

```
page.xpath('//link[contains(@rel, "icon")]').each do |icon|
  p icon.attr('href')
end
```

And received:

```
"https://ownwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/cropped-favicon-32x32.png"
"https://ownwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/cropped-favicon-192x192.png" 
"https://ownwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/cropped-favicon-180x180.png"
```

Here is a [Replit](https://replit.com/@razvan-sv/HideousYummySupport#main.rb) that returns all the images.

Comment: Thank you.This is working i tried this in some different way and got result.

Answer (score 0):

```
page.search('link').each do |link|
      if link['href'].to_s.include?(".gif") or link['href'].to_s.include?(".png")  or link['href'].to_s.include?(".jpg")  or link['href'].to_s.include?(".jpeg")
      puts link['href']
      end
    end
```